How to work with three different laptops to print to two different printers?
My organisation runs events with lots of last minute and mid-event printing needed. We use a standard back and white laser for bulk prints/copying and a colour printer for printing credentials.
Depending on who is doing the admin at the moment of the request, three different people working at their laptop will be the person doing the requested printed.
At the moment, there is lots of swapping of wires to enable this.
Is there a hub, switch, block of ports that I can set up so that all the laptops are connected to both the printers?

Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic... That said, it should be obvious that network printing is what any organization uses since decades ago.

Sorry - should have also said that this printing takes place in basically tents at various sports grounds around the country where the only networking is a wifi dongle.

Again, your question is off-topic. Commenting here as a courtesy only. There are multiple mobile routers in the market, same can work with a battery for many hours.

@DouglasMcLellan please do not use comments to add information ... edit the question instead

What the printers are is 'useful' here - do they natively do wifi or ethernet? Can you set up a mobile router to network these machine? What you have on hand is going to affect the answer you get hugely.

All that is fair points. Setting up a device to act as a print server seems the way to go as I can control what devices are used if that is the solution and is documented (and laminated) for them to follow wherever they are.

Post your question on Hardware Recommendations site

With WiFi available you should be able to Use any network printing functionality of the devices. Please share model details to receive further help here.
In case the printers are not networking ready, you can easily set up a printing server with a small/energy efficient Raspberry Pi Zero (W) and connect all printers via USB to it. This would share all connected printers in the network with all client devices.
See an example tutorial here:

https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-print-server/


That looks like a good way to go. Thanks for pointing me in that direction.
